# Linear variable differential transformer operation as load position feedback

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors, transformer, winding

I was doing some research on servo position systems and saw that Linear Variable Differential Transformers are used as feedbck systems that feeds the current load position to an error detector. So I know that it is made up of a primary winding and two secondary windings with a movable core and the output signal depends on the core's position. But I'm still not sure how this actually monitors the feedback of a load such as flight control surfaces, which I'm studying.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: [LVDT wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_variable_differential_transformer)

Comment: There are ready made LVDT demodulator chips which will provide both supply voltage and demodulate the LVDT output. You can simply consider it as a sensor which will provide voltage proportional to the amount of movement between the two ends of the LVDT. **One end of the LVDT is connected to the aircraft and other end to the movable flight control surface**. The relative movement is the output. You can convert it into angle.

Comment: What do you mean by one end of the LVDT? Connected to the core? And is the demodulator the one that converts it into an angle?

Comment: A LVDT looks like a bicycle shock absorber with one cylinder sliding into a pipe shape. The ends of the lvdt : one end is the end of the cylinder. second end is the end of the pipe. the LVDT measures how much the cylinder slides in and out of the pipe shape. you can do a web search for pictures. [No affiliation](https://shop.elkome.com/en/d602500a-l50-miniature-lvdt-displacement-sen)

Comment: The demodulator rectifies the oscillating output of an lvdt and processes it (ratio of two voltages) and gives a voltage signal. The demodulated voltage is proportional to the lvdt extension/compression. The extension of the LDVT is in units of length e.g. mm. It has to be converted into angle based on geometry.

Answer (score 0):

An LVDT is a displacement sensor having a range of 0...  1 mm or 0...  +/- 0.5 mm upto 0...  10mm or 0...  +/- 5mm or 0...  25mm.

It's function is not related to load.

It's output could be 0...10 V, -5 V...+5 V, 4... 20 mA etc.

It could be used, for example, to measure thickness through relative measurements or to determine the position of a slide from it's home position.

Answer (score 0):

A (badly) drawn diagram showing how the LVDT can monitor the flight control surface's angular position.
The grey parts show the cross section of the wing. It has two parts a fixed part (left, bigger) and movable part (i.e. control surface). The movable part can rotate about a hinge.
The LVDT is shown as two rectangles (red / orange). One part of is connected to the winding and other part to the movable core.

When the flight control surface is moved (bottom figure), the two pats of the LVDT move relative to each other. The resulting signal from the coils can be rectified and processed (ratio of voltages). The voltage is calibrated to indicate the change in length of the LVDT from neutral position (top figure).

The changing length is marked by the blue arrow. It is part of a triangle completed by two green arrows. The green arrow lengths are fixed. From the length of the green arrows and the blue arrow (measured by LDVT), we can workout the angle by which the control surface has moved.

[image: aircraft wing cross section]

Actual photo below (taken and modified from stratosjets[dot]com). The probable position of the control system (including LVDT) is marked with an arrow. It is hidden in a protective aerodynamic covering.

[image: flight control surface photo]

### Note

LVDT does **not** measure feedback of a **load**, as in force/torque. It measures linear movement, which can be converted into angular movement in the case of flight control surfaces.

Comment: [Video 1](https://youtu.be/-dNwnzdZOkg?t=29) Actuator visible, LVDT may be integrated into the actuator (not visible).